# how to switch class between two elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think this question might already been asked, but I can't find any answer working nor questions that reflect my problem. My problem is I currently have 2 `<div>`'s and I would like them to switch class after a `onClick` event.
For example, when I click on a div, I'd like it to have a class called `isSelected` and if the 2nd div have the class, I'd like to remove it. I don't simply want the clicked div to toggle `isSelected`, I'd want the other div to 'loose' it's `isSelected` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a class selector to target any element with the certain class, and remove it....

```
$("#myDiv").on("click", function() {
    $(".isSelected").removeClass("isSelected");
    $(this).addClass("isSelected");
});
```

This would work no matter how many selectable divs you have...

Comment: jee ... i was so close to the solution, i was trying to figure out a way to find this behavior, i knew it'd be that simple ... anyway that works so thank you fella !

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(".divclass").click(function(){
   $(".divclass").removeClass("isSelected");
   $(this).addClass("isSelected");
});
```

Assuming these two siblings have same class `divclass`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("div").click(function(){
   $("div").removeClass("isSelected");
   $(this).addClass("isSelected");
});
```

```css
.isSelected {
    background-color:red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">test 1</div>
<div class="">test 2</div>
<div class="">test 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one div will allways have the class you can use

```
$("#myDiv").on("click", function() {
    $('#div1, #div2').toggleClass('isSelected');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need.

```js
$("div").click(function(){
   $("div").removeClass("isSelected");
   $(this).addClass("isSelected");
});
```

```css
.isSelected {
    background-color:blue; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">1</div>
<div class="">2</div>
<div class="">3</div>
```